# How to copy text to clipboard from specific table cell in razor view?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

What I'm trying to do is to copy the text from 'Message' column to clipboard.

And the problem is when I click on a 'Copy message' button, it only copies the first message in the first row.

So is there any solution to this in razor view?

```
             ....
@foreach (var item in Model.Customer)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.id
                    </td>
                    <td >
                       <span id="messageText"> @item.message</span>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <button id="copyButton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="copyToClipboard('#messageText')">Copy Message</button>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        @item.name
                    </td>                 

                    <td >
                        @item.lastName
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>

JQuery:

  function copyToClipboard(element) {
                var $temp = $("<input>");
                $("body").append($temp);
                $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                $temp.remove();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is setting the `Id` attribute value of the span to `messageText` **inside the loop**. This will create more than one span with the same `Id` attribute value. When you call the `copyToClipboard` method, you are passing the jQuery Id selector expression (`'#messageText'`) to get the DOM element. The `Id` selector will always return the first element which is matching the Id ,hence you are always getting the first message.

> In a document, Id's should be unique. Duplicate Id attribute values in
>   a document is invalid markup.

You should not hardcode a static value as the `Id` attribute value inside a loop. Use a more generic selector get the data.

```
@foreach (var item in users)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Id
        </td>
        <td >
            <span class="messageText"> @item.message</span>
        </td>
        <td >
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="copyToClipboard(this)">Copy</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and the script where we will use the relative selector methods like `closest` and `find`

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var msg = $(element).closest("tr").find("span.messageText").text();
    alert(msg);
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(msg).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

There is a more simpler and effective way to handle this use case. Why not directly pass the message to the `copyToClipboard` method ?

```
<td>
     <button class="btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('@item.message')">Copy</button>
</td>
```

and

```
function copyToClipboard(message) {
     var msg = message;
     alert(msg);
     //use msg now
}
```

I like this approach as i am not touching the DOM at all to get the message (using any jQuery code)

Comment: Thanks you so much! It works as planed. :-) For future visitors of this post in jQuery code there's a typo, you wrote .messageText instead #messageText.

Comment: See the second part of answer where i am passing the message string directly to the method. I prefer that approach because it avoids touching the DOM to get the message.